# Intertwined java generic interfaces and classes

Tags: java, generics

I have a very specific problem with java generics. The follwowing classes and interfaces have been predefined:

```
public interface IFirst<R, T> {...}

public abstract class AbstractFirst<T extends AbstractFirst, L extends IFirst<String, T>> {...}

public interface ISecond extends IFirst<String, AbstractSecond> {...}

public abstract class AbstractSecond extends AbstractFirst<AbstractSecond, ISecond> {...}
```

Now I've created a following repo definition which seems to be valid:

```
public abstract class AbstractRepo<T extends AbstractFirst<T, IFirst<String,T>>> {...}
```

But now that i want to extend it:

```
public class RepoFirst extends AbstractRepo<AbstractSecond> {...}
```

I get the following error:

```
Bound mismatch: The type AbstractSecond is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter 
<T extends AbstractFirst<T,IFirst<String,T>>> of the type AbstractRepo<T>
```

I cannot change the first four (at least not radically) beacuse they are too heavily ingrained with the rest of the application, but the second two are new and up for change if need be.

Also intrestingly it allows the following (with raw type warnings):

```
public class RepoFirst extends AbstractRepo {
   ...
   @Override
   AbstractFirst someAbstractMethod() {
      return new AbstractSecond() {...};
   }
   ...
}
```

But for code clarity I would like to implement it with clearly defining AbstractSecond as the generic type for Abstract Repo.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AbstractRepo` expects an instance of `IFirst` and not a subtype of `IFirst`. But your `AbstractSecond` is clearly not `IFirst`. (I mean it is, from a OO standpoint but for generics, `List<Number>` is not the same as `List<Integer>`). It's ISecond. It might work if you could change your `AbstractRepo` from `IFirst` to `? extends IFirst` as you did for `AbstractFirst`.

Comment: Downvoter has a better answer or explanation? I don't mind the downvote but it'd help me in correcting if i know what is unacceptable here.

Comment: Don't know who downvoted you answer, but it was just the one I needed. Thank you

Comment: I believe you AbstractRepo should be declared as `public abstract class AbstractRepo<T extends AbstractFirst<T, ? extends IFirst<String,T>>>` ? If so, please let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Finally this worked for me: 
public abstract class AbstractRepo<T extends AbstractFirst<T, ? extends IFirst<String,T>>>

Comment: @Vampnik - I don't know who you are and I don't know what you are trying to achieve. I can't even think of what scenario could possibly necessitated such a design. All I can say is may the force be with you as your project grows.